# Is it possible to add wpf ResourceDictionary in the Application from a UserControl xaml file?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to add a ResourceDictionary in the application level from a UserControl xaml.

i.e. do the same thing from UserControl xaml than the following in C#:

```
if (Application.Current == null) new Application();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() {...});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an `ApplicationDictionaryMerger` class that accepts dictionaries as its content and adds them to the `MergedDictionaries` of the application, for example:

```
[ContentProperty("Dictionaries")]
public class ApplicationDictionaryMerger
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ResourceDictionary> dictionaries = 
        new ObservableCollection<ResourceDictionary>();

    public ApplicationDictionaryMerger()
    {
        this.dictionaries.CollectionChanged += this.DictionariesChanged;
    }

    private void DictionariesChanged(object sender,
                                     NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do whatever you deem appropriate here to get the MergedDictionaries
        var applicationDictionaries = 
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;

        // Enhance this switch statement if you require more functionality
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var dict in e.NewItems)
                {
                    applicationDictionaries.Add((ResourceDictionary)dict);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public IList Dictionaries
    {
        get { return this.dictionaries; }
    }
}
```

The only catch then is that you need to instantiate an object like the above from XAML.

Initially I thought that adding it to the `Resources` section of any control in your XAML would be fine, but then it turns out that the XAML loader does not instantiate resources that are unused. So I came up with another workaround: setting the object as the value of any control's `Tag` property.

**I 'd be very interested to know if there's a better way of ensuring that the `ApplicationDictionaryMerger` is instantiated.**

Here's how to use it:

```
<Grid>  <!-- can also be any other control -->
    <Grid.Tag>
        <sandbox:ApplicationDictionaryMerger>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!-- add all resources you need here -->
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- you can also add more dictionaries here -->
        </sandbox:ApplicationDictionaryMerger>
    </Grid.Tag>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The "ContentProperty" is called "MergedDictionaries", but the property in C# class is "Dictionaries" and in xaml, it's "ResourceDictionary"... ther must be some typos?

Comment: @sthiers: "MergedDictionaries" should indeed be "Dictionaries" as the property -- thanks for the catch there. In XAML you just use the name of the class you want to put in the `Dictionaries` collection, there's no typo.